# When is there an inner product making a given matrix unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, unitary-matrices

The unitarity of a given operator/matrix $A$ depends on the underlying inner product, so I guess it in principle possible for a given non-unitary $A$ to act as a unitary with respect to a different choice of inner product.

Is this ever possible? If yes, are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ that make it unitary with respect to some inner product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diagonalizable matrix with all eigenvalues of modulus 1 is "unitarizable" by selecting an inner product in which its eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are all mutually orthogonal.

Comment: is this also a necessary condition?

Comment: @glS Yes, because a unitary matrix in a given inner product space is diagonalizable with all eigenvalues of modulus 1 and this fact is not changed by changing the inner product.